# Matching resolution and extent of rasters, what is the best practice?

Tags: raster, matching, resolution, terra, extent

after several errors I finally managed to match my raster data but now I have a more or less general question. I`m still quite new and would like to understand what´s happening with my data.
I have two sets of data->meteorological (MD) and reflactance (RF) they differ ins resolution and extent. First step was to match the resolution with disagg() this worked (but it´s a bit strange because when I checked them in ArcGIS pro and measure the pixels they are still 1000m, maybe someone know why. When proceding my calculations in R it seems fine and there is no error massage that resolution doesn´t match)

To match the extent I used ext(MD_crop)<-ext(RF_crop). I don´t understand what it is doing with my data
When i use resample() it also works but there the values change and I don´t want that do happen. Can someone mybe explain the differences between these two "functions" a bit deeper? What would be the best practice in my case?

I didn´t really find a satisfying answer in the forum so far.

I tried to provide an example hopefully this works.

```
#create reproducable example
MD <- rast(nrows=71, ncols=49,vals=c(21.25958,63.43917))
crs(MD) <- "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs " 
ext(MD)<-ext(c(610027.5, 659027.5, 5263464, 5334464))
res(MD)<-1000


RF <- rast(nrows=6944, ncols=3864,vals=c(0,9402))
crs(RF) <- "+proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs " 
ext(RF)<-ext(c(612760, 651400, 5262480, 5331920))
res(RF)<-10

#disaggregate MD
MD_10<-disagg(MD, fact=c(100,100))


#crop rasters by extent
Ext<-ext(c(614630,649880,5266632,5321782))

MD_crop<-terra::crop(MD_10,Ext,snap="near", ext=TRUE)
RF_crop<-terra::crop(RF,Ext,snap="near", ext=TRUE)

> MD_crop
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 5515, 3525, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 614627.5, 649877.5, 5266634, 5321784  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
> RF_crop
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 5515, 3525, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 614630, 649880, 5266630, 5321780  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 


#change witch extent-> this one is working but I don´t really understand
#what it is doing, does it change values? how does it get matching extents?

ext(MD_crop)<-ext(RF_crop)

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 5515, 3525, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 614630, 649880, 5266630, 5321780  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 



#resample<-dimension and resolution fits but values change
MD_resample<-resample(MD_10,RF_crop)

class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 5516, 3525, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 614630, 649880, 5266630, 5321790  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
> RF_crop
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 5516, 3525, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 10, 10  (x, y)
extent      : 614630, 649880, 5266630, 5321790  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=33 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: way back at the start, when you first create RF and MD, do project(RF, MD) and look into how the GDAL warper works, you have options for the algorithm in use (by default "bilinear" for numeric data, "nearest" for integer or categorical data as applied by terra)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I don´t really understand it. The function project() from terra changes my coordinate reference systems and I don´t want to do that. The MD and RF is just created here as an example with the same values as the data I´m working with. For my work I don´t have to create data., I just have t match theire extents and resolutions  Or am I understanding you wrong. Maybe you can specify your answer a little bit

Comment: project() matches its first argument to the resolution and extent of its second, by modifying the data - you can set any target raster and then project(RF, target) project(MD_10, target) so they now will match - when you set ext of one raster to that of another you're simply shifting the canvas underneath and possibly stretching it, it won't change the data in a meaningful way - warping is about matching resolution and extent, the change crs is not the crux it's optional

Comment: Thanks again, now I understand it way better and it works fine. So you would say project() is a more proper way to do it? Then I´ll go for that option

Comment: I think so, personally I'd prefer a less opaque interface to the GDAL library but  ... so I wrote my own, but it's good when other packages with the same capability don't prevent this advanced usage :)